# How to calculate a cubic root in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

in kotlin there is an internal **math library** and I only find the **square root** but there is no cubic root.

[image: cubic root]

```
import kotlin.math.sqrt
import kotlin.math.pow

fun Formule(a:Int):Double{
    //no working
    //rs = a.pow(1/3)
    //function
    retun rs
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val calc = Formule(9)
}
```

Comment: `a.pow(1.0 / 3.0))` works fine for me.

Comment: Because it ends up with '4.99999999'. See: https://pl.kotl.in/ByK-x4-t4

Comment: @Todd good point; I only tested it with OP's example of 9 and got the same result for both.

Comment: @royer You can achieve that without using Java libraries. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to use **Java libraries**, just use the **Kotlin** one:

```
import kotlin.math.pow

fun formula(a:Int):Double {
    return a.toDouble().pow(1/3.toDouble())
}
```

Just tested it:

```
println(formula(9)) //2.080083823051904

println(formula(27)) //3.0
```

Comment: In that case you should probably also use `pow` instead of `Math.pow`.

Comment: @Louis  tank you

Comment: @royer You're welcome. If this answer was helpful, please accept it so everyone can benefit from it. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need Kotlin multi-platform support, the Java standard library has [Math.cbrt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#cbrt(double)), which can be called safely from Kotlin.

```
val x: Double = Math.cbrt(125.0) // 5.0
```

Comment: ohh, fantanstic, tank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Program: Kotlin program to calculate the cube root of 125
     * Date: Tue, 6-4-2021
     * @author: ANKUR SAXENA
     * Platform: Windows 10 Pro/x64/Kotlin v1.4.31/VS Code
     */

    // cube root logic, var result = (Math.cbrt(num))

    // program start
    // main function
    fun main (args: Array)
    {
        // declare variables
        var num: Int = 125

        // print value
        println ("Value of the number: $num\n")

        // calculate cube root
        var cubeRoot: Double = (Math.cbrt(num.toDouble()))

        // print cube root
        println ("\nCube root of $num is: $cubeRoot\n")
    }

// program end
```

// save this file as 'CubeRoot1.kt' 
// compile: $ kotlinc CubeRoot1.kt [hit Enter] 
// execute: $ kotlin CubeRoot1Kt [hit Enter]

output:

```
    Value of the number: 125


    Cube root of 125 is: 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin 1.8, you can simply do :

```
import kotlin.math.cbrt

fun main() {
    val num = 27

    println("The cube root of ${num.toDouble()} is: " + 
        cbrt(num.toDouble()))
}
```

[cbrt() in Kotlin 1.8](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#cbrt)